# how to change the date format in talend

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

I have two scenario's,which I couldn't able to solve.
PLZ help me.

Scenario 1:
I've two files Source_1_table(Excel file),Source_2_table(Excel File).
Attached screenshot
I want to compare the source_1 date to source_2 date.
If the source_1 date is matching with source_2 date then the status should be as "Y" if not match then the status should be "N".
Here I am trying with this code row1.date.equals(row2.date)?"Y":"N"
Note:both columns are string data type. 
[image: Screenshot]

Scenario_2:
Here source_1 SAL column have a null value.and source SAL column have a VALUE.
While I am trying to compare the source_1 sal value with source_2 sal value getting null pointerException.
I am trying with this code relation.Is(source_2.sal)?" ":source_2.sal.equals(source_1.sal)?"Y":"N"

I want to replace a value with empty space or "empty" in null value.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this snapshot.

[image: Screenshot Talend]

Scenario 1: `“ row1.Date.equals(row2.Date)?"Y":"N"”` is working if both Source 1 & Source 2 contain dates as `string`.

Scenario 2: To avoid the Null Pointer Exception, check for null values before comparing Source 1 and source data.  Please try the expression below:

```
(row2.SAL == null || row2.SAL == ("")) ? "" : row1.SAL == row2.SAL ? "Y" :"N"
```